# SQL query execution time identical what best to do?

Tags: sql, performance, select, benchmarking

I have 2 tables with many columns, one is for saving the site settings and the other is to save the users data both table have about 40 column

When I test the speed of query example

```
SELECT config.*, user.* 
FROM config, user 
WHERE config.id = 1 AND user.user_id = 1
```

the execution time of that query is 0.0003 sec

Then on the other hand if I do

```
SELECT 
    user.user_id, user.user_name, config.language, config.url 
FROM 
    user, config 
WHERE 
    config.id = 1 AND user.user_id = 1
```

then the query execution time is again 0.0003

I ask myself why should I bother doing it the second way if both are executed in same time? If someone has a good explanation, please let me know - thanks

Comment: Execution time will be the same -- but data transferrred will be less with the second -- saving bandwidth and if the client is remote will result in a faster response for them.  Go with #2.

Comment: They're the same because you're testing with a relatively small amount of data over a local connection. They won't be the same when you get larger amounts of data over a remote connection. You should bother yourself to do it the second way because it's the proper way to do it. (And both of them are wrong; you should never have a comma in your FROM clause. That syntax has been replaced decades ago. Use a proper JOIN.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @KenWhite the thing with a proper join is to achieve it it need to have at least 1 common column

Comment: @Mireille28 - That is not true - your `ON` clause does not need to refer to any column at all - it just needs to evaluate to `TRUE`